# Font-awesome icon displays a box

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I added the font-awesome CDN Html link from the website and placed in the head, and still, the icon wouldn't show. I'm new to Html and need specific instructions on how to fix this.

I even tried downloading it and linking the file locally but that didn't work.

```html
<head>
  <title>Social Media</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the icon `fas fa-search` is from Fontawesome version 5, but you are loading Fontawesome version 4.7.
Fontawesome 4.7 has instead the `fa fa-search` icon.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
    <title>Social Media</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<ul>
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please check first what font you are using i mean latest or old there are old 4.7.0 there are different between fa and fas